# Django's ORM Model.objects.raw() query causes an infinite recursion error

Tags: python, django, inheritance, recursion, django-orm

I have the following (simplified) models:

```
class Common(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Common, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._initial_data = {}
        self.track_fields(
            'date_created',
        )

    def track_fields(self, *args):
        for field_name in args:
            self._initial_data[field_name] = getattr(self, field_name)


class Directory(Common):

    directory_path = models.TextField()
    parent_directory = models.ForeignKey('self')

class File(Common):

    removed = models.BooleanField()
    parent_directory = models.ForeignKey(Directory)
```

Now, I'm trying to query some objects like this (a simplified example, pay no attention to why sql was used in the first place):

```
sql_select_dirs_of_deleted_files = '''
    select d.id, directory_path
    from directory d
    left join file f on f.parent_directory_id = d.id
    where f.removed = true and f.id in %s
    group by d.id, directory_path
    order by directory_path asc
    '''
dirs_of_deleted_files = Directory.objects.raw(sql_select_dirs_of_deleted_files, [tuple(file_ids)])
parent_of_top_dir = dirs_of_deleted_files[0].parent_directory
```

Accessing `dirs_of_deleted_files[0]` causes an infinite recursion error on line

```
self._initial_data[field_name] = getattr(self, field_name)
```

in the Common model. I am aware of the recursion problems in inheritance and using getattr, but using `models.Model.__getattribute__(self, field_name)` does not seem to make a difference here. However, what DOES work instead is:

```
dirs_of_deleted_files = Directory.objects \
    .filter(files__in=file_ids, files__removed=True) \
    .distinct('id', 'directory_path') \
    .order_by('directory_path')
```

Now, accessing `dirs_of_deleted_files[0]` does not cause any infinite recursion errors.

The Common model is inherited by several other models, and instantiated lots of times in different places obviously, and the `getattr()` never caused any problems, until using this `Directory.objects.raw()` method. Why not? I would be suspect it a bug in Django, but I'll hold my judgement.

Comment: I added the class Meta that is essential for your example. By contrast you could also simplify the example and keep it so consistent that the problem can still be reproduced. Both is recommended at Stackoverflow. Fortunately your question is interesting enough and it can be fixed.

Comment: Much appreciated! You are right, the example could be both simpler and more complete. Will fix it shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is known in [**Django ticket #22858**](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22858).

> If you access a field in `__init__()`, you should include it in all of your `only()` calls to avoid hitting the database again for each item in the queryset.

It is a common consequence of [`defer()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer) docs:

> Each deferred field will be retrieved from the database if you access that field (one at a time, not all the deferred fields at once).

The problem can be reproduced if the method `__init__` does access any two or more deferred fields (i.e. fields deferred by `.raw()`, `.only()`, `.defer()` methods) then every access triggers a database query and a new temporary instance is created that needs again the same fields.

**A minimalized example of the issue**

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        (self.a, self.b)

class Test(TestCase):
    def test(self):
        SomeModel.objects.create(a=0, b=0)
        SomeModel.objects.only('id')[0]
        # RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

**FIX**

You can fix it by the condition `field_name in self.__dict__` because you probably don't need to track the field sometimes if you don't need to load it.

```
def track_fields(self, *args):
    for field_name in args:
        if field_name in self.__dict__:
            self._initial_data[field_name] = getattr(self, field_name)
```